# How to access removable storage dcim directory on android?

Tags: java, android, android-external-storage, removable-storage

I understand the difference between external and removable storage.

I'm making an app that can access the pictures (so far basically just a file browser). My pictures currently save on my removable storage.

When I use Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), it is giving me sdcard0- which is the external. My removable storage is sdcard1- how can I access this?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: There is no official access to removable media prior to Android 4.4, and there is no means of getting at an arbitrary directory on removable media on Android 4.4: http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html